# jQuery syntax for creating multiple elements

Tags: jquery

What is the proper syntax for creating multiple HTML elements with jQuery when using the JSON format?  For example...

```
inputs = $("<select/>", {
    html: list,
    id: 'select'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
    name: 'select'+siteNumber+'['+x+']'
    });
```

creates a select input, but I have about 6 other input fields (of different types, not just submit) that I want to store in the `inputs` variable.  How can I put more than one element into the variable?

Thanks very much.

Comment: You may want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438178/jquery-caching-multiple-selectors-to-one-variable) and its answers... not a dupe, but you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use some loop and push your new elements in array.

```
var inputs = [];
for (var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
    inputs.push($("<select/>", {
        html: list,
        id: 'select'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
        name: 'select'+siteNumber+'['+x+']'
    }));
}
```

Comment: I should have been more specific - they are not all select elements.  Regardless, this may do the trick...